# Not able to display video file in HTML (Django app) in Chrome or Safari

Tags: html, django, video

I'm embedding the video in HTML using the following code,

```
{% block contents %}
<video name='demo' controls autoplay width='50%' height='40%'>
    <source src="{{ STATIC_URL }}vid3.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
{% endblock %}
```

From the view in which it should display, I see a black box with controls (a play button), but there's no video to play. This video is stored locally, and I'm not sure as to why it won't display.

Help?

Comment: Black box appears if the path is not correct. Can you check the STATIC_URL and overall path of video. Path should be relative to the project folder/container

Comment: I've right now put the video in the same folder as this template (I won't keep it there... I was just trying to get it to work). STATIC_URL is set to "/static/", and the path of the video is "my_project/my_app/templates/my_app/vid3.mp4".

Comment: Did it worked after that?

Comment: What do you think the file path should look like?

Comment: read the docs for Django static files, the same path as the template is not the right place to put the video file https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

Comment: Hmmm I tried putting it in "my_project/my_app/static/my_app/"...

Comment: View source is your friend

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't doing it exactly right. Following that doc exactly gives me what I want. Thanks!